# Openstreetmap data in AR.js + Three.js

Tags: three.js, ar.js

In location-based AR.js+Three.js how would I go about creating markers - for example building outlines or street paths - based on OSM data?

The examples I found seem to use measurements in some sort of three.js space, whereas OSM data provides lat-lon coordinates.

Is there some functionality to convert coordinates into three.js units of measure, or do I have to do that from scratch?